# slideToggle() toggles out of screen

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a problem with jquery's slideToggle().I'm toggling my footer using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.close').click(function(){

            $('#footer').slideToggle();
            if( $(this).hasClass('active') )
                $(this).text('show');
            else
                $(this).text('hide');

        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });     
});
```

on a website that is pretty long.When I close or open the footer,I can always see the div I use to toggle the footer,but when reopening,the footer slides out of the screen(so that you would have to scroll down in order to see it).How can I change this so that the footer gets shown in the part of the screen I am currently in?(well,I hope it's clear what I mean because i can not upload anything onto my webhoster atm).

http://jsfiddle.net/bm45k0ps/

Comment: We can't comment on HTML we can't see.

Comment: Fiddle would be helpful..

Comment: added it,but there are lots of lines as its a full site(i excluded some unrelated stuff,but i wanted to keep the placeholder so you could see how the slide out works when the site gets longer and longer)

Comment: If you're talking about your document's height changing when you show and hide the footer, you can use `animate({scrollTop: value}, duration);`. See http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for information on animate, see http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/ for information on scrollTop, and see http://papermashup.com/jquery-page-scrolling/ for how to implement it (Demo is available on the page)

Comment: no footer con in your fiddle

Comment: @ctwheels you mean it would be better to animate a scrolldown to the actualfooter?

Comment: @gruntswilldie Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/bm45k0ps/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Version 1: animate concurrently..

```
        $('#footer').slideToggle(500);
         $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#footer").offset().top + $("#offset").height()
            }, 500);
```

Version 2: animate after slideToggle is done..

```
        $('#footer').slideToggle(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#footer").offset().top + $("#offset").height()
            }, 500);
        });
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bm45k0ps/7/)...

Comment: Works really well in the fiddle,problem is:when i use it local on my browser(chrome),it first goes in a "normal" speed and when it it reaches the links + headlines,it stops for like 0,1 sec before completing the slide, looking like a lag.is there any possibilty to change this?

Comment: I'm not experiencing any issues with this. Works fine for me

Comment: Could it depend on the screen width?As I said I have no problem on it with the fiddle but on my pc screen theres a little lag.

Comment: What does depend on screen width ?

Comment: this delay I'm experiencing especially when closing(although I'm not sure why it  should make a difference)

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bm45k0ps/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.close').click(function(){

            $('#footer').slideToggle(function(){

            }, function(){
            $('html, body').animate({ 
            scrollTop: $("#footer").offset().top + $("#offset").height()
        }, 800);
            });
                if( $(this).hasClass('active') )
                    $(this).text('Footer anzeigen');
                else
                    $(this).text('Footer verbergen');

            $(this).toggleClass('active');


        });

});
```

you can do something like this